# touchpad scroll area not working since upgrade to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, hp-touchpad

Since my upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 the vertical and horizontal scrolling using my touchpad does not work. My laptop is an HP Pavilion DV6.

Comment: stuff that "stops working" are probably bugs - maybe a bug report on launchpad would be better here to help resolve this.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue on Dell 7737 touchpad as well. Stopped working after upgrade to 14.04.  Reported the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1310044

Comment: Initiating the following via CLI got my horizontal scrolling working: Try this via CLI, then reboot.  Worked for me.

    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled "true"

Comment: What if it's not a bug, but a mere question? and the OP doesn't have sufficient knowledge to figure out what exactly is the problem?